# mysqldump | gzip - $? is always set to 0

Tags: bash

I am dumping databases in a loop, if I try and dump a database that doesn't exist I get the stderr 
`mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'yes' when selecting the database` as I would expect, however despite the error `$?` always returns 0.

My code is below:

```
for database in ${databases[@]}; do
    $dumpcmd $database | gzip > "$backupdir/$database.gz"
    result=$?
    echo "dumped database: $database ($result)"
done
```

I want to detect an error from mysqldump and print it to the screen - I have a hunch this is related to the pipe to gzip, but as a C# dev trying to learn bash I am stuck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to check what's in `PIPESTATUS`:

> ```
>    PIPESTATUS
>           An  array  variable (see Arrays below) containing a list of exit
>           status values from the processes in  the  most-recently-executed
>           foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).
> ```

So instead of `result=$?`, try `result=${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

Comment: `set -o pipefail` at the beginning of the script checks this array when you use `result=$?` for any non-zero and if none are non-zero returns zero.  So if any part of your pipe has an error `result=$?` will return the error number

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$?` will give you the return status of the **last** executed command, what is gzip in this case. But `gzip` won't care about `mysqldump` error messages. They are just regular text output for it, which can be compressed.

Change your example to something like this, to become aware of the return status of `mysqldump`:

```
for database in ${databases[@]}; do
    # dump to a temporary file
    $dumpcmd $database > temp.sql
    # check mysqldump's return status
    result=$?
    if [ $result != 0 ] ; then
        echo "mysqldump error"
        exit 1
    fi
    gzip temp.sql > "$backupdir/$database.gz"
    echo "dumped database: $database ($result)"
done
```

Comment: why not somthing like:(im new to bash) `($dumpcmd $database || echo "$dumpcmd exited with $?" 1>&2) |
(gzip > "$backupdir/$database.gz" || echo "./b exited with $?" 1>&2)`

Comment: Looks good! Why not answer this? :) I just wanted to keep things simple

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to make sure your dump works before executing your zip:

```
($dumpcmd $database || echo "$dumpcmd exited with $?" 1>&2) | (gzip > "$backupdir/$database.gz" || echo "echo exited with $?" 1>&2)
```

or you could `set -o pipefail` at the beginning of your script to make the pipeline’s return status the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, OR zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully.